# jQuery .css() returning incorrect min-width from an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a JS/jQuery function that receives a percentage, turns it into px so a chart is initialized. However, I have an if clause to assure that the percentage given will be bigger than the element's min-width. When I try to save the min-width into a variable with

```
var testw = $(elem).css("min-width");
```

it returns me "0px". My element's css is:

```
#chartHolder{
width:1140px;
min-width:1152px;
height:230px; 
margin-left: -10px;}
```

I have to set an initial width so my API recognizes the chart. But right before it is show, I throw my function:

```
function redTudo(elem, percAlt, percLarg) {
var p1 = percAlt / 100;
var p2 = percLarg / 100;
var width = parseInt(window.innerWidth * p2) - 10;
var testw = $(elem).css("min-width");
if (width < parseInt(testw)){
    width = parseInt(testw);
}
if (window.innerHeight < 768) {
    var height = parseInt(768 * p1);
} else {
    var height = parseInt(window.innerHeight * p1);
}
$(elem).css({"width": width + "px", "height": height + "px"});}
```

Can anyone diagnose where I could be mistaken?

---

UPDATE:

This is how I'm calling it:

```
redTudo("#chartHolder", 40, 90);
```

I'm using KoolChart and declaring this element is nuts, but the most important line is:

```
KoolChart.create("chart1", "chartHolder", chartVars, "100%", "100%");
```

The second argument is my id. It initializes my graph correctly, and assumes my width and height as well. However, my min-width is still the problem.

Comment: It works ok in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c244zj80/1/) - maybe you're not defining `elem` correctly?

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/c244zj80/2/) your function working with it. Notice how the function is called. How are you calling your function?

Comment: Your problem exists somewhere outside of what you've described. Please reduce the problem to something reproduceable in a jsfiddle. Currently it is impossible to figure out where your problem is.